# "Ambigous Redirect" for redirecting text to a variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm making a shell script to limit the amount of time someone spends on a program but it gives me these errors:

```
./time_limit: line 26: $Log: ambiguous redirect
./time_limit: line 16: [: root: unary operator expected
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
config (){
ImageViewer=/ 2> /dev/null 
AllowedTime=30 #in minutes
AllowedPlays=1
cmd=sol #for demonstration, I use sol installed by default in Ubuntu. Set to your liking
AllowedUser=root #Set to your liking.
ImageViewer=eog #I set this to the Eye of GNOME image viewer. If no GUI or if you don't want an explosion (really?) comment out.
#If you have another desktop change to yor image viewer.
Log=/dev/null #if you want to log this, set to file of your liking
#but make sure you have write permission.
config
date=$(date)

}
if [ $USER = $AllowedUser ]
then 
    echo "ACSESS ALLOWED for $AllowedTime minutes."
        at now + $AllowedTime minutes <<< "killall $cmd; $ImageViewer ../files/Explode.gif"
    echo "Session 1: $date" >> $Log
    $cmd
    exit
fi
echo "ACSESS DENIED!"
echo "This UNAUTHORIZED USE has ben recorded."
echo "Violation by $USER $date" >> $Log
```

I ran it though ShellCheck and it seems fine. Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: I refuse to believe shellcheck didn't warn you about quoting your variables.

Comment: @jesse_b, it doesn't seem to, actually. It does mention the one where `$USER` isn't quoted, but not the ones about `$Log`. I think what happens is that it sees the _constant_ assignment `Log=/dev/null`, and figures that's safe even if unquoted. But it doesn't realize the function with that assignment never runs... Comment out the assignment, and it complains about using an unset variable, _and_ reminds about quoting it. For once, not a straight missing quotes issue :)

Comment: note that the code here does seem to call `config` but it does that from within the function itself. If the function was ever called in that form, it'd nest the function call endlessly, and e.g. Bash just crashes if you do that... (zsh and ksh seem smart enough to just detect and complain about recursing too deep without crashing)

Comment: Please don't add "solved", "resolved", etc.  to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `config()` function is never actually called in this snippet, so it will never be executed; therefore, those variables are never set.  I think you meant to but accidentally put the call to `config` within `config` itself, making it an infinitely recursive function.

You need to call `config`, but you should also quote all your variables.

```
$ unset foo
$ [ $USER = $foo ]
-bash: [: jesse_b: unary operator expected
$ [ "$USER" = "$foo" ]
$ echo foo >> $foo
-bash: $foo: ambiguous redirect
$ echo foo >> "$foo"
-bash: : No such file or directory
```

Note that the redirection to the unset variable `$foo` in the example above provokes the "ambiguous redirect" error from the shell when the variable is unquoted.  The solution is to make sure that the variable is set (by correctly calling `config` in your case), and to additionally quote all the expansions.

Setting the `nounset` option with `set -o nounset` or `set -u` (or adding `-u` option to `sh` / `bash` in the shebang) can also help identify the cases where variables are being expanded when not initialised.

Properly indenting your script would also have helped spot the problem here.